# Extract numbers from String using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as below:

```
String str="tile tile-2 tile-position-1-4"
```

I wish to receive the numbers in an array,such as `[2,1,4]`.

My own solution is to break the string using `split`, but i am wondering if there is a shortcut using `Regx`

Thanks to @nitzien with Regx it tried:

```
String pattern= "^tile tile-(\\d*) tile-position-(\\d*)-(\\d*)$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
System.out.println(m.group(0));
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

But, it complains with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

Comment: Will there be always three numbers in whole of string?

Comment: Yes, it is a pattern.

Comment: try this `String[] result =Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D")).filter(s->!s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 1):

```
regex pattern - "^tile tile-(\d*) tile-position-(\d*)-(\d*)$"
replacement - "[\1,\2,\3]"
```

Replacement is string which you will need to convert to array depending on which language you are using.

Updated answer after edited question

```
String str="tile tile-2 tile-position-1-4";
String pattern= "^tile tile-(\\d*) tile-position-(\\d*)-(\\d*)$";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(pattern, "$1,$2,$3"));
```

This will give

```
2,1,4
```

Comment: i have updated my question, do you have any idea?

Comment: What is classname in Matcher m = r.matcher(className);?

Comment: it is `str` sorry

Comment: Please check updated answer